# "Folder view" is reset to desktop when monitor is connected

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, plasma-5

I did a right-click on the desktop and went to Desktop settings -> Wallpaper screen, where I changed "Layout" combo from "Desktop" to "Folder view". I did it because I want to see my files as icons on the desktop.

When I connect my external monitor via HDMI, this setting is reset back to "Desktop", so I don't see the icons anymore. Anyone knows how to make the setting persistent?

I tried this on 2 different computers, one of them having a dedicated Nvidia GPU, the other having integrated Intel GPU. The problem is present on both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it by using more recent KDE version. This is done by adding Kubuntu Backports PPA to software sources:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

In theory your system might get less stable, but I've been using it for a week and haven't experienced any problems or crashes.